# "Cannot read property 'match' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, match

I have that script:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('utm_term');

$(document).ready(function() {

if (dynamicContent.match(/buy/i)) {
    $('#buy').show();
}

else {
    $('#default-content').show();
}
});
```

When in url there is any parametr it's working fine and else working, #deafult-content showing.

Problem that when i have clean url without parametr #default-content don't showing because "Cannot read property 'match' of null".

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are returning `null` for `!results`, which you can then not `match` against.

try combining your two checks and return an empty string:-

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {

  if (!url) 
    url = window.location.href;
  
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  
  if (!results || !results[2]) 
    return '';
  
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('utm_term');

$(document).ready(function() {

  if (dynamicContent.match(/buy/i)) {
    $('#buy').show();
  } else {
    $('#default-content').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="default-content" style="display:none;">test</p>
```